# Сравнение товаров Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

На сайте установленно "сравнение" товаров при переходе на страничку сравнение товаров не отображает анонс картинки , применяется класс no-image.

```
if (isset($arItem['FIRST_PIC'][0]))
{

?><img class="image" src="<?=$arItem['FIRST_PIC'][0]['RESIZE'][0]['src']?>" 
alt="<?=$arItem['FIRST_PIC'][0]['ALT']?>" title="<?=$arItem['FIRST_PIC'][0] 
['TITLE']?>" /><?
                                        }
else
{
?><img class="image" src="<?echo SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/img/noimg.png" title=" 
<? echo $arItem['NAME']; ?>" alt="<? echo $arItem['NAME']; ?>"><?
}
```

Comment: а что у вас тут $arItem['FIRST_PIC']?

Comment: ну а вы смотрели почему не поулчаете нужные данные в `$arItem['FIRST_PIC'][0]`? разберитесь и все получится

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, потому что `$arItem['FIRST_PIC'][0]` пустой